# Can't control volume for bluetooth headset on Windows

Tags: windows-8, usb, audio, bluetooth

**Problem**

If I start my computer I can hear sound with my bluetooth headset and I can control the volume/mute the sound. But often, if I reconnect the bluetooth headset without restarting computer, I loose control of the volume. The actual volume coming from the headset is suddenly fixed at one level.

However, I can scroll the volume control up and down, even to 0. But it doesn't affect the actual volume from the headset. How do I stay in control over the volume when I reconnect the device?

**Helpful info:**

- I'm scrolling at the right device, since the audio-device has it's
  own logo. It also shows the "jumping bar", that represents sound, in
  the volume control.
- I can reduce the volume for individual apps through the "volume mixer", even mute applications. But not the master volume.
- I can mute inside applications, e.g. mute a youtube video.
- Windows 8 Pro
- Headset: Goji G4BOEBK15
- Bluetooth adapter: Belkin Bluetooth adapter 4.0

[image]

Edit:
I have an "USB to audiojack"-soundcard for my microphone plugged in. It's completely separated from the headset.

Answer (score 2):

this probleme occurs in Windows 8. i suggest you :
once the device is paired, right click on the volume icon in system tray, then select "playback devices". in the pop up window, do you see your Bluetooth headset listed? if so, select it, then click the "set default" button. audio should get re-routed to the headset itself. if not, look around in that window. there may be other options. you can click on properties for said device, configure, etc.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This does not always work but you try it.  In Windows 10, go to Control Panel->Devices and Printers.  Look for your Bluetooth headset listed under the Devices category, right click on it and select "Control".  This brings up the "Bluetooth Device Control" screen.  On it is a button labeled "Connect".  Click the Connect button and you will then be able to see that the volume control is now connected to your headphones.  This procedure works best for me if I already have another device, like my phone, playing music, turn on the headphones so they connect to the phone and play through the headphones, turn off the playback, and then click the "Connect" button on the PC.

[image: Bluetooth Device Control]

Comment: Thanks. this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Badr Bellaj's answer, but mine was already set to Default Communications device, but what made it work was to set something else to the default device and then back to the Bluetooth headset.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me in windows 10. I had to go in sound properties, select device, advanced settings tab and disable audio enhancements.

Windows 10 sound properties (in french!)

[image: screenshot of sound properties - in French]